# Issue when writing a simple code using for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, error-handling, unhandled-exception

this is the error :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD16B7FE7C in Project1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0000000B2FAFF760.
```

here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main() {

    
    string word;
    
    cin >> word;

    cout << word.size() << endl;

    
    for (int i = 0; i <= word.size(); i++)

        cout << word.at(i) << endl;




    return 0;
}
```

im also still not sure where the code breaks it, it just takes me to a weird window with A LOT OF LINES that i have no idea what they mean.

i tried debugging, rebuilding, trying some alternative ways to write the code that i know of and nothing worked, like the code is so simple HOW AM I OUT OF MEMORY XD.

Comment: If `word.size()` is `0`, how many characters does your program try to print?

Comment: Loops using `<=` as a terminating condition are frequently wrong, as this one is.

Comment: _it just takes me to a weird window with A LOT OF LINES that i have no idea what they mean_ Could that be a stack trace? Those are usually useful, since they show you where the error occurred.

Comment: If you had used `[]` instead of `.at` it would have "worked." The former accepts indexes one more than the latter. And it's legal for reading.

Comment: General rule of thumb: If you see a `<=`  in the exit condition of a loop, examine the loop. You probably have a bug.

Answer (score 3):

In this for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= word.size(); i++)

    cout << word.at(i) << endl;
```

the variable `i` is being changed in the range `[0. word.size()]`. However the member function `at` throws exception `out_of_range` when its argument is equal to or greater than the value returned by the member function `size()`.

So change the for loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)

    cout << word.at(i) << endl;
```

Pay attention to that opposite to the member function `at` the index of the subscript operator may be equal to the value of `size()`.

That is you may write

```
for (int i = 0; i <= word.size(); i++)

    cout << word[i] << endl;
```

though there is no great sense to use the index equal to the value of size().

To avoid such a mistake it is better to use range-based for loop like

```
for ( char c : word )

    cout << c << endl;
```

or

```
for ( const auto &c : word )

    cout << c << endl;
```

Comment: I've said it before, but I like your style, Vlad from Moscow. Always thoroughly helpful!

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Thanks. You are a kind man.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
```

If you have `size` elements in `word`, the loop will run `size` times, not `size + 1` times.